# Memory leaking in custom Subscribable class

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, subscription

After implementation of the custom `Subscribable` class in the project.

I receive memory leaking in the app.

Code of the class.

```
open class Subscribable<T> {
    private var _value: T?
    private var _subscribers: [(T?) -> Void] = []
    open var value: T? {
        get {
            return _value
        }
        set {
            _value = newValue
            for f in _subscribers {
                f(value)
            }
        }
    }

    public init(_ value: T?) {
        _value = value
    }

    open func subscribe(_ subscribe: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
        if let value = _value {
            subscribe(value)
        }
        _subscribers.append(subscribe)
    }
}
```

I have assumption that `_subscribers` will hold strong references to the array.

Comment: Do you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception, can you add this info in full, generics sometimes cause memory leaks, also if possible please provide implementation (usage of class), it will also help if someone provide an alternative, also helpful to paste in playground and see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that by default properties are with a **strong** reference.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID52

Not specifying **weak** or **unowned** may create reference cycles.

Also items in an array have a strong reference coming from that array as well.

You might want to check out this

https://marcosantadev.com/swift-arrays-holding-elements-weak-references/